# How can I space out one element on the left and three on the right with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML but it's not doing what I want:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Label Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
   <Label Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" />
   <Label Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="End" />
   <Label Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="End" />
</Grid>
```

To make it simple I didn't include the Text and other properties. Note that I want to use auto as this perfectly sized the elements.

What happens here is that all four columns appear on the left. But what I would like is to have column 0 on the left and columns 1,2 & 3 on the right with a space in between.

Does anyone have an ideas as to why the last three columns do not go to the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say the column width is Auto, it will check the necessary size for its children, in this case the label, and won't adjust to the StartAndExpand.

You can edit the first column to type GridUnit.Star, and will fit the remaining space.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```